# Does Gurobi's Runtime attribute include time for the interface

Tags: matlab, optimization, gurobi

I call Gurobi from some Matlab program to solve an optimization problem `model` with `result = gurobi(model)`. From Gurobi's website, I get that with `result.runtime`I obtain the

> Runtime for the most recent optimization (in seconds). Note that all
>   times reported by the Gurobi Optimizer are wall-clock times.

What exactly does runtime include? In particular, I want to know if it makes a difference, i.e. if there is some overhead in the communication from matlab to Gurobi which contributes to the runtime, if I read a model from an .mps-file and directly solve it, i.e.

```
model = gurobi_read(model.mps);
result = gurobi_read(model.mps);
time = result.runtime;
```

or if I do manipulations to the model before actually solving it, i.e.

```
model = gurobi_read(model.mps);
model.A(model.sense=='>',:) = -model.A(model.sense=='>',:);
model.rhs(model.sense=='>',:) = -model.rhs(model.sense=='>',:);
model.sense(model.sense=='>') = '<';
result = gurobi(model);
time = result.runtime;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Runtime](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/runtime.html) attribute reports the solve time only; it does not include any runtime from the APIs.  Part of the reason for this is that all Gurobi interfaces are built on the [C API](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/c_api_overview.html), so the MATLAB interface obtains the runtime value from the C API, which does not know about any MATLAB overhead.